# Sending a JSON request to an Azure Function App from an Azure Logic App sometimes causes values to become malformed

Tags: c#, json, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app which uses Compose to build a JSON object:

```
{
"status": "Completed",
"result": [
  {
    "id": "some_hash_here",
    "distance": 0,
    "value": 240032
  }
]
}
```

This Compose sends this to an Azure Function using the 'Call Azure function' block and a POST method.

The Azure Function is written in C# and uses the usual HttpRequest manner to get that request.

However, when that function gets the JSON for some reason it looks like this:

```
{
"status": "Completed",
"result": [
  {
    "id": "some_hash_here",
    "distance": 0.0,
    "value": 240032.0
  }
]
}
```

This causes issues of course. I don't understand where this conversion is happening has the diagnostics in Azure Logic App tell me the Input to the Call Azure function block was correct but when the C# code get's it it's been mutated!

There's no deserialization going on at this point either, it's literally what the function get's in the request so something is changing this?

I've tried using a Parse JSON block to force it into a schema but that still doesn't stop the change happening and actually can cause my C# to throw an Object Reference error!

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment and below are my expected results:

**`Design:`**

[image]

**`C# Azure Function code:`**

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string reqBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(reqBody);
    string status = data["status"];
    int distance = data["result"][0]["distance"];
    int value = data["result"][0]["value"];
    log.LogInformation($"Hello Rithwik Bojja !! ,Status: {status}, Distance: {distance}, Value: {value}");
    
    string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(status)
        ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
                : $"Hello Rithwik Bojja !! ,Status: {status}, Distance: {distance}, Value: {value}";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
}
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Use above code to get expected result as i have got. Else I would suggest you to raise a support request as yours is abnormal behavior.